# Azure adds timestamp at the beginning logs

Tags: azure, docker, azure-log-analytics

I have a problem with the logs retrieving from my docker containers with Azure log analytics, all logs are retrieving well but Azure adds a date at the beginning of each line of the log, which means that an entry is created for each line and I can't analyze my logs correctly because they are divided...

For example on this image I have in the black rectangle an added date (by azure I think) and in the red rectangle the date appearing in my logs :

[image: query with two dates]

Also, if there is no date on a line of my logs, there is still an added date on all lines, even the empty ones

[image]

The problem is that azure cuts my log file line by line by adding a date on each line when I would like it to delimit with the dates already present in my logs files.

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: where do you see the logs? via query or something else?

Comment: Yes via query, With ContainerLog table

Comment: Please add your query in your post, and it would be better share a screenshot of the query result where the timestamp added.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you clearly, if the you mean the timestamp in the Timestamp column, then it's easy to filter out it.

Comment: I'm going to put some screenshots

Comment: I updated my request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Azure Monitor for containers doesn’t support multi-line logging, but there are workarounds available. You can configure all the services to write in JSON format and then Docker/Moby will write them as a single line.

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-faq#how-do-i-enable-multi-line-logging

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution I can think of is that, when you query the logs, you can use the [replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/replacefunction) method to replace the redundant date(replace it with a empty string etc.). And you need to write the proper regular expression for your purpose.

A false query like below:

```
ContainerLog 
| extend new_logEntry=replace(@'xxx', @'xxx', LogEntry)
```

Comment: When I make my request directly in log analytics?

Comment: @MaximePomier, I'm sorry, what do you mean "when I make xx"?

Comment: Do I have to add it directly to my query: "ContainerLog", as in the image I added? Do you have an example with a false request

Comment: @MaximePomier, I added a query in the post, but you may need do some research by yourself.

Comment: The main problem with this extra date is that it makes the log file badly delimited in the Log analytics entries, instead of having one entry for a stackstrace there is one per line, I'm not sure the replace can fix that

Comment: @MaximePomier, can you explain more clear about "instead of having one entry for a stackstrace there is one per line"?

Comment: For example, I have this stacktrace: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
        at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookTitles(Author.java:25)
        at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)
Azure will create one entry per line when I want to have all the lines of this stacktrace in the same LogEntry